# Why does .items() work for the multiplication between sequence and `float`

Tags: python, pytorch

I got two dicts `self.theta` & `self.beta` whose values are all fp and a fp value `eta`, when I tried to modify it as below:

```
self.theta[0]=self.theta[0]-eta*self.beta[0]
```

It returned `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`.
If I put it into a for loop of the dict, **it worked**, but I cannot separately manipulate with a single key such as [0] above, have to finish the modification in the for loop in this case.

```
for key, value in self.theta.items(): 
      self.theta[key]=self.theta[key]-eta*self.beta[key]
```

I wonder is it possible to directly modify the `self.theta[0]` without getting the error? The numpy array seems like a workaround but I need to change the code a lot so I am thinking about solely torch methods.

p.s. I know the list cannot multiply with fp, but how come the for loop iterates the `.items()` works? Full scripts below:

```
beta = defaultdict(list)
theta = defaultdict(list)
layer = [500,300,100,3]
eta = 0.1
i = 0
for l in layer[0:-1]:
    # print(l)
    theta[l] = (torch.randn(l, layer[i+1]))/math.sqrt(l)
    beta[l] = torch.Tensor(l, layer[i+1])
    i += 1


theta[0] = theta[0] - eta * beta[0]
# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

for key, value in theta.items():
    theta[key] = theta[key] - eta * beta[key]
    print('theta:', theta[key])
# This is okay
```

Comment: Either `eta` or `self.beta[0]` is not a float as you claim.  I'm going to assume that it's `self.beta[0]` that's the problem, because your looping code that works doesn't access that at all, but successfully uses `eta`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. All of your input data is missing, which makes it hard to understand what's happening. BTW, did you mean to replace `self.beta` with `self.dE_dTheta`?

Comment: Hi @jasonharper, sorry about the previous typo. I have already matched that two. both `self.beta` and `self.theta` are dictionaries with fp values. I think in the for loop it access the `self.beta` which is not fp.

Comment: Hi @wjandrea, thank you for the reminder. I have posted the snippet above please take a look at it.

Comment: In your updated example code, your dicts do not have a `0` key - their keys are the values from `layer`.  Since they're initialized as `defaultdict(list)`, attempting to retrieve the `0` key gives you an empty list instead - so your failing calculation is actually `[] - 0.1 * []`.  If the multiplication hadn't failed, the attempt to subtract from a list would have.

Comment: @jasonharper I just realized that. Such a careless mistake, thank you for the help.